# Using Instruments with XCode, how can I see a list of all objects currently in memory?

Tags: xcode, instruments

Using Instruments with XCode, how can I see a list of all objects currently in my app's memory?

Is there a way to view it as a big UML type chart? I'd prefer to be able to visualize the relationships at any given moment while the app is paused. But just a hierarchical tree view of some kind would be fine too.